# Traceability Matrix

Tags: php

I am creating a traceability matrix for PRD. I have test case _id which is coming as row of the tables. And requirement id is coming as my column. I using php table creation..

this is the code i am using

```
<th>Requirement:</th>
        </tr>

          <?php
            foreach($q['cases'] as $case)
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$case['requirement_id']."</td>";
                foreach($q['cases'] as $case)
                {
                   //echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
                   for($i=0;$i<count($case['id']);$i++)
                   {
                    if($case['requirement_id']==true)
                    echo "<td>OK</td>";
                   }
                }
                echo "</tr>";

            }
            ?>
```

i want to do check a "ok" mark per case_id ..I mean if there is a requirement_id corresponding to a case_id then only "ok" mark ll be there else blank.
so according to my program each line will have only one "ok" , not every cell.

Comment: yes i want "ok" in se-144 and 782 crossing cell i.e (1,1) cell in the matrix.

Comment: Have you tried the new code? Could you also please delete all the comments in my answer?

Comment: yes.it's showing nothing

Comment: cause is my requirement_id != case_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<th>Requirement:</th>
        </tr>

          <?php
            foreach($q['cases'] as $case)
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$case['requirement_id']."</td>";
                foreach($q['cases'] as $c)
                {
                   //echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
                    if($c['requirement_id']==$case['requirement_id'])
                        echo "<td>OK</td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";

            }
            ?>
```

The problem was that you were calling two foreach loops with the same variable name `$case` and that might got confused.

Comment: i want to choose requirement_id corresponding to case_id

Comment: i edited in your answer section..anyway now i updated in the real question

Comment: hey..according to the new code i am not getting any output :(

Comment: if($case['requirement_id']==$c['requirement_id'])
                        echo "<td>OK</td>";

Comment: @learning_bee, good corrected. Could you please delete all the comments? These are not useful to every one :)